# Fatal error: illegal expression while running AFNI bash shell

Tags: bash, mask

I want to run the following script in shell

```
for i in {1..10};
    do
    3dcalc -a COLUMNS.nii -expr ‘equals(a, "${i}”)’ -prefix col_"${i}”.nii;
    done
```

but I am getting errors, *COLUMN.nii* file is the nifty file with a collection of masks with value ranging from 1 to 10 and I want to separate these masks into individual nifty file using this AFNI command in a *for* loop.

[image: This is the error that I receive]

Comment: The actual *question* is about `bash`, not mask, neuroscience, or neuro-image. http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ - Please c.f. [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for guidelines on asking good questions. (And try `vi`, or even notepad.) ;)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you may have edited your code using a word processing program, such as Microsoft Word, which doesn't put "normal" single- and double-quote characters into the file.

In your program the line

```
3dcalc -a COLUMNS.nii -expr ‘equals(a, "${i}”)’ -prefix col_"${i}”.nii;
```

has those "curly" single- and double-quote characters. Change this to

```
3dcalc -a COLUMNS.nii -expr 'equals(a, "${i}")' -prefix col_"${i}".nii;
```

When editing code I recommend that you use a programming-specific editor - there are many out there - rather than a word processing program.

Comment: Mind, I suspect that the OP probably wants _both_ `${i}`s to be expanded, which this answer doesn't accomplish